# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to raw type 'DarwinBoolean'

Tags: xcode, swift2, xcode7

Cross-posting this from the Apple Developer Forums (https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/59905#59905).

We recently tried building our project with the Xcode 7 GM version for the first time. The issue we encountered, which I explain below, still persists in Xcode 7.0 (7A220).

The project consists partly of old Objective-C code and partly of some newer Swift code. When compiling, the build process fails with the following error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: cannot convert value of type 'Int' to raw type 'DarwinBoolean'  
<unknown>:0: error: cannot convert value of type 'Int' to raw type 'DarwinBoolean'
```

The line that runs before this error is:

```
CompileSwift normal x86_64 <path_to_project>/PDFViewController.swift
```

As this did not seem very helpful, we started trying to locate the error by doing the good old "comment all code and uncomment until it breaks"-approach.

I traced the location the error is thrown to one line in that file (PDFViewController.swift). When I comment that line out, the code compiles, if I leave it in, I get the above error. The line is nothing special, it just calls an Objective-C service that is supposed to return an NSArray of attributed Strings:

```
var attributedStrings: [NSAttributedString] = orderService.attributedStringsForNotes(notes)
```

The declaration of thet method is:

```
- (NSArray<NSAttributedString *> *) attributedStringsForNotes:(NSString *) aString;
```

Commenting its whole implementation does not resolve the compile-time issue, so I am starting to think this might be an Xcode bug.

Is there something I am missing? Or some more detailed error message I could obtain?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Sorry I cannot provide a smaller Minimal Working Example, I just did not know how to isolate this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so we have fixed this issue. The error message proved to be quite unhelpful as expected.

The issue turned out to be quite a stupid one. The `orderService` mentioned above had a method declared in the `.h` file which was unimplemented in the `.m` file and never used. The fact that it was unimplemented seems to have triggered the compiler error with the incredibly unhelpful message about `Int` not being convertible to `DarwinBoolean`.

Removing the declaration in the header file (or implementing the unneeded methods) solved the issue.